# Using DisplayAttributes with a series of radio buttons for one variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, displayattribute

I'm writing an MVC application, and I have a view for editing users, which contains a series of possible user roles. Each user has exactly one role, so I'm using radio buttons for the "UserRole" property, each of which gives it a different value
e.g.

```
<div class="form-inline">
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.UserRole, UserRoles.GlobalAdministrator)
    @Strings.GlobalAdmin
</div>
<div class="form-inline">
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.UserRole, UserRoles.VenueAdministrator)
    @Strings.VenueAdmin
</div>
<div class="form-inline">
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.UserRole, UserRoles.None)
    @Strings.BasicUser
</div>
```

Which works fine, but I'd rather use a Display Attribute to be more consistent with the rest of my code. Is there an easy way of setting the `UserRoles` Display attribute to do this?
(e.g., in a different ViewModel I have)

```
[Display(ResourceType = typeof(Strings), Name = "VenuePermissions")]
public IEnumerable<int> SelectedVenuePermissions { get; set; }
```